# OTP screen design - How to make the texField non clickable for editing but can only become active when last textField is done?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wrote this code for 4 textfields accepting each of the four characters for OTP. However I also want the user to avoid going to a random textfield themselves:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if(((textField.text?.count)! < 1) && (string.count > 0))
        {
            if textField == charForOTP1
            {
                charForOTP2.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else if textField == charForOTP2
            {
                charForOTP3.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else if textField == charForOTP3
            {
                charForOTP4.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else if textField == charForOTP4
            {
                charForOTP4.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            textField.text = string
            return false
        }
        else if( (textField.text?.count)! >= 1) && (string.count == 0)
        {
            if textField == charForOTP2
            {
                charForOTP1.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else if textField == charForOTP3
            {
                charForOTP2.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else if textField == charForOTP4
            {
                charForOTP3.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else if textField == charForOTP1
            {
                charForOTP1.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            textField.text = ""
            return false
        }
        else if (textField.text?.count)! >= 1
        {
            textField.text = string
            return false
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I have tried implementing the same. However it resulted in some unexpected results. 
What exactly should I add here for the same to work?

Comment: You can enable/disable user interaction, this will help you only required textfield will be active and the user has to click only that one.

Comment: What happens if the user has enter 3 digits and the second digit is removed by the user? Will he be able to enter the 4th digit? Will the 3rd digit also be automatically removed?

Comment: @PiyushRathi, yes i tried that. But when a user presses back key on a textfield, he should also go to last textfield. I am unable to figure out that as this function doesn't detect backspace on empty textfield.

Comment: You have to check which key pressed, if it is backspace and that textfiled contains text then remove it, or if texfield empty pass control to the previous textfield.

Comment: what if user entered something wrong and he is on 3rd textfield and wants to go back? @PiyushRathi

Comment: @PiyushRathi, thank you for your help. it will be kind if you help me with this question i asked above.

Comment: @YereHore why you want to avoid user to go to random textfield?

Comment: @YereHore I hope I got your requirement, Initially only first textfield will be active, when user reaches to last textfield and inputed entry all textfields will active. right?

Comment: @YereHore is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I hope your requirement is as:

First, you need only one `textfield` active, as soon as user inputted value next respective `textfield` will become active when reached to the last `textfield` you want to enable all `textfields`.

1. We need to add notification when `textfield` value changed in `viewDidLoad` method. (I have taken otp1, otp2, otp3, opt4 textfields also assign tags from 1 to 4 to all textfield).

   ```
    otp1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
    otp2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
    otp3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
    otp4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
   ```
2. I have written `updateTextFields(textfield: UITextField)` function which will updates whatever actions need to give to active/inactive textfield. To active first textfield we need to call `self.updateTextFields(textfield: otp1)` from `viewDidLoad`.

   ```
    /// Updates actions for current textfield
    ///
    /// - Parameter textfield: 'UITextField' object
    func updateTextFields(textfield: UITextField) {
      var enableArray = [UITextField]()
      var disableArray = [UITextField]()
      var sTextField: UITextField = UITextField()
      switch textfield.tag {
      case 1:
        sTextField = otp1
        enableArray.append(otp1)
        disableArray.append(otp2)
        disableArray.append(otp3)
        disableArray.append(otp4)
        break
      case 2:
        sTextField = otp2
        enableArray.append(otp2)
        disableArray.append(otp1)
        disableArray.append(otp3)
        disableArray.append(otp4)
        break
      case 3:
        sTextField = otp3
        enableArray.append(otp3)
        disableArray.append(otp2)
        disableArray.append(otp1)
        disableArray.append(otp4)
        break
      case 4:
        sTextField = otp4
        enableArray.append(otp4)
        enableArray.append(otp1)
        enableArray.append(otp2)
        enableArray.append(otp3)
        break
      }
      for ltextfield in disableArray {
        ltextfield.isEnabled = false
      }
      for ltextfield in enableArray {
        ltextfield.isEnabled = true
      }
      sTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
   ```
3. Now the actual `UITextFieldDelegate` method to check the inputted character.

   ```
    // MARK: UITextField Delegate Method
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      if string != "" {
        var text = textField.text ?? ""
        text.append(string)
        if text.count > 1 {
            return false
        }
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789 ")//Here change this characters based on your requirement
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
      }
      return true
    }
   ```
4. At last, our notification method which we have added in `viewDidLoad` method. Here we have checked textfield count and based on that we have move curser.

   ```
    @objc private func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
      if textField.text?.count == 1, (textField.tag + 1) < 5 {
        self.updateTextFields(textfield: self.getTextField(isForward: true, currentTextField: textField))
      } else {
        if textField.text?.count == 0, (textField.tag - 1) > 0 {
            self.updateTextFields(textfield: self.getTextField(isForward: false, currentTextField: textField))
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Hope this will helps you.

**EDIT**

Added Get Text field Method

```
/// Get TextField Object For Responder which is either active or resign
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - isForward: flag used to find whether we want next or previous text field
///   - currentTextField: TextField which is active
/// - Returns: TextField if it satisfied condition
func getTextField(isForward: Bool, currentTextField: UITextField) -> UITextField {
    if isForward {
        if (currentTextField.tag + 1) < 5 {
            switch currentTextField.tag {
            case 1:
                return otp2
            case 2:
                return otp3
            case 3:
                return otp4
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (currentTextField.tag - 1) > 0 {
            switch currentTextField.tag {
            case 4:
                return otp3
            case 2:
                return otp1
            case 3:
                return otp2
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return UITextField()
}
```

Comment: thank you @piyush.. i cant vote to this but you deserve it

Comment: I hope it works for you. I checked it and this works as per requirement, but if you want some changes you can do it.

Comment: what is self.getTextField ?? can you paste this method also